# What word means breaking something that is already broken?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am writing an essay on Shakespeare’s *Othello* and need a fitting word that means something along the lines of breaking something that is already broken as a result of other means. My phrase is:

> [...] drove the blade deep into his ____ heart.

I need a word there that describes the fragile state of the heart after it has been (emotionally) broken through love (in a bad way) and is about to be killed through a physical object. In this case, the blade being pushed into the man’s chest.

Hopefully my question makes sense, I am struggling to put my thoughts into text but if you need any clarification, please ask.

Comment: I'm not offering this as an answer since it doesn't fit your sample, but the same sentiment is expressed by the idiom [rub salt in the wound](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/rub+salt+in+a+wound), meaning to intentionally make poor feelings worse.

Comment: If it ain't fixed, don't break it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about ***tormented***?

> **torment** - great mental suffering and unhappiness, or great physical pain: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/torment

Google Books shows 4,480 results for "tormented heart", among them:

> That agonized, tormented heart, which at the beginning so awfully
>   relieved itself in the rush of blood and the bursting of his pores, at
>   length broke.
>
> I kissed him tenderly upon the lips and felt desire and yearning
>   multiply within his tormented heart.
>
> Give me time to repair my tormented heart and to see the future more
>   clearly.
>
> There I stood in a world created by thought and suffused with feeling,
>   and with me, the lonely woman into whose tormented heart I had peeped
>   in that arrestive moment.
>
> The combintion of wine and his beloved only child, they knew, would
>   provide the necessary solace to the tormented heart of their master.

It is also the title of two songs, [Tormented Heart](https://www.musixmatch.com/lyrics/Sarah-Vaughan/My-Tormented-Heart) and [My Tormented Heart](https://www.musixmatch.com/lyrics/Sarah-Vaughan/My-Tormented-Heart).

Answer (score 0):

> Drove the blade deep into his **vulnerable**  heart.

> Able to be easily physically, emotionally, or mentally hurt, influenced, or attacked

([Dictionary.Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/vulnerable))

The word *vulnerable* connotes this state of fragility that you need, if not saying that they have already been hurt.

Answer (score -1):

There are many words in English which are close synonyms of *break*, but most of these have slightly different emphases. In this case I would suggest [*fractured*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/fracture), which although technically meaning the same as *broken*, has the implication that the fractured object has not yet fallen apart.